# How to correct the compiler error saying incompatible types?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

```
/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
    int[] arr= {1,2,1,1,2,3};
        HashMap <Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> hm= new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>();
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            if(hm.get(arr[i])==null)
            {
                hm.put(arr[i],new ArrayList<Integer>());
                hm.get(arr[i]).add(i);
            }
            else
                hm.get(arr[i]).add(i);
        }
        int[] res= new int[6];
        for(Map.Entry m:hm.entrySet())
        {
            ArrayList<Integer> p=m.getValue();
            for(int i=0;i<p.size();i++)
            {
                int s=0;
                for(int j=0;j<p.size();j++)
                {
                    if(i!=j)
                        s=s+Math.abs(p.get(i)-p.get(j));
                }
                res[p.get(i)]=s;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<res.length;i++)
            System.out.print(res[i]+" ");
    }
}
```

It is giving compiler error:

> Main.java:28: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to ArrayList
>               ArrayList p=m.getValue();
>                                              ^
>   1 error

Why it is showing incompatible types?

Comment: Your `Map.Entry` is raw. You should add the appropriate types to it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifying the type of the iterator. Change:

```
for(Map.Entry m:hm.entrySet())
```

to:

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> m:hm.entrySet())
```

Comment: ... and sprinkle in a few spaces as well for legibility